# Espelhar inputs com seus valores

Tags: html, jquery, array, input

É possível o jquery entender os elementos de um valor array vindo do html? *ps: não sei se é correto dizer que no html tem uma array.*

Estou criando com html e jquery um **input** dinâmico que está tendo o valor do `name` como se fosse uma array, somando 1 pra cada inserção ;

`name="nome=[]", name="nome=[1]", name="nome=[2]"...`

*isso é para faciltar o PHP selecionar os dados.*

Esses inputs criados são **espelhados** numa outra `<fieldset>`.

Quero espelhar os `values` chamando o elemento pelo `name` consegui isso usando o `.keyup()` do jquery, mas ele funciona só para o primeiro input, que em tese seria o `nome[]`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir desse jeito que imaginei, tentei criar um **for** pra chamar cada elemento da "array ". Pelo jeito, da maneira que pensei o seletor só fica no `nome[]`.

Botei na cabeça fazer desse jeito que talvez não esteja enxergando outras maneiras de resolver isso. Tentei tbm com um `.click` em um botão, aonde os values dos inputs do primeiro `<fieldset>` copiassem nos values dos inputs do outro `<fieldset>`, pensei isso por ambos terem o mesmo name.

O que seria indicado ?

**Código estudo** - Edit#1

*Na parte do Java Script está comentado duas maneiras, uma sugerida pelo @Matheus Cuba e uma maneira que fiz pegando pelo #ID, mas gostaria de usar a tag `name`*

https://jsfiddle.net/10nkpt2x/5/

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você tem vários elementos `input` com `name="nome=[2]"`, quando você atualizar um deles quer todos os outros inputs com esse mesmo name sejam atualizados pra este valor?

Comment: Matheus, mais ou menos! Eu não sei quantos inputs vão ter pois é dinâmico, vai somando. O que eu tenho em mente é como vou ter dois elementos com o mesmo `name` penso que poderia copiar o valor de um em outro. Vou atualizar minha pergunta com uns "códigos estudos" sobre o caso ai vc vê melhor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema parece ser de *delegação*. Ao usar `$("seletor").keyup`, os elementos adicionados de forma dinâmica não estão incluídos no evento.

Para solucionar, use:

```
$(document).on('keyup','input[name^="nome"]', function() {
```

Desta forma, os novos elementos serão escutados pelo evento:

```js
/*-- Essa é a maneira sugerida por @Matheus Cuba ---*/
var soma = 0;

$(document).on('keyup','input[name^="nome"]', function() {
  var identificador = $(this).attr('name');
  var valor = $(this).val();
  $('input[name^="' + identificador + '"]').val(valor);
});

$('#botao').click(function(){
      soma++;
      
      $('<input id="clone'+soma+'" class="f" name="nome=['+soma+']">').appendTo('.box0');
      $('<input id="clonec'+soma+'" class="f" name="nome=['+soma+']">').appendTo('.box');
      
      });

$('#x').click(function(){
  if ( soma > 0 ){
    $('.f:last-of-type').remove();
    
    --soma;
}
    });

contador = function(){
    alert(soma);
}
```

```css
div {

display: flex;

}

p {

width: 100%;
margin:0 0;
color:grey;

}

#x {

color: lightblue; 

}

#botao {

color:coral;}

#x, #botao {

text-align: center;
font-size: 3em;

}

#botao:hover, #x:hover {

cursor: pointer;

}

h1:hover{

cursor: pointer;

}

.box0, .box {

margin: auto;
color:grey;

}

fieldset {

text-align: center;
width:15em;
border: none;

}

input {

text-align: center;
margin-top: 15px;

}

.cont { 

display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p id="botao">+</p><p id="soma" onclick="contador()">ALERT DA SOMA</p><p id="x">-</p></div>


<div class="cont">

 <fieldset class="box0"><input name="nome=[]" placeholder="nome" id="clone0"></fieldset>
   
     
 <fieldset class="box"><input name="nome=[]" placeholder="espelho" id="clonec0"></fieldset>
        
</div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado ! eu não estava enxergando a capacidade do evento `on()` iluminou agora :)

Answer (score 2):

Tente este Snippet:

Assim, você coloca uma trigger global nos elementos cuja o atributo `name` comece com `nome` (*Trocadilho Maravilhoso*)

```js
$('input[name^="nome"]').keyup(function() {
  var identificador = $(this).attr('name');
  var valor = $(this).val();
  $('input[name="' + identificador + '"]').val(valor);
});
```

```css
hr {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Campo 2:<input name="nome=[2]"><br> Campo 2:<input name="nome=[2]"><br> Campo 2:<input name="nome=[2]"><br>
<hr> Campo 4:<input name="nome=[4]"><br>
<hr> Campo 3:<input name="nome=[3]"><br> Campo 3:<input name="nome=[3]"><br> Campo 3:<input name="nome=[3]"><br>
```

Comment: Coloquei no corpo da questão os códigos , está um esqueleto do que estou pretendendo fazer, do jeito com o #ID ele funciona bugado, pra sair o value nos outros inputs precisa escrever no ipunt primeiro, e depois , se vc clicar em alguns inputs hora ele funciona, hora não.