# Check List marca e exclui apenas itens já existentes

Tags: javascript

Tenho um check-list feito em js, onde o user digita a tarefa e ela aparece na lista. Mas só consigo marca como "task concluida" ou "excluir task" as tarefas já existentes, ou seja, quando incluo uma task nao consigo excluir e nem marca-lo.

Segue codepen: https://codepen.io/fmm312/pen/mXBqKd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema de delegação. Altere os *event handlers*:

```
$(document).on('click','.checked-task',function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.name-task').toggleClass('name-task-toggle');
});

$(document).on('click','.remove-task',function(){
    $(this).parent().hide('slow');
});
```

Elementos adicionados de forma dinâmica não estão no DOM. Logo a sintaxe acima consegue escutar novos elementos.

> Já há algumas respostas com o mesmo problema: [resposta 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274000/8063),
>   [resposta 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275762/8063), [resposta 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273062/8063).

Comment: Perfeito, resolvido !